# Does it take more effort to move against earth's rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, relative-motion

I know that if we stand still, we are traveling at 0 m/s relative to the Earth.

But if we move against the rotation of the Earth we lower our speed, so, wouldn't we have to fight against the atmosphere? The atmosphere (i.e. the air) is still moving fast, while we are running against the wind?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that relative to earth, if we stand still, we are traveling at 0
>   m/s, but if we move against it, thus lowering our speed, wouldn't we
>   have to fight against the atmosphere? Atmosphere and thus air is still
>   moving fast, while we are running against the wind?

There is no wind in either direction, because the air is moving/ rotating at exactly the same speed as the Earth and you. Therefore in either direction you run you are altering that equilibrium and 'fighting' against the atmosphere, as you say.

Comment: Yes, I know that the atmosphere and earth are traveling at the same speed. But if I run East, ahead of the atmosphere's speed, shouldn't I make less effort to move, since I'm ahead of it? And if I slow down my speed by traveling West, the wind would still be traveling at the same speed (faster than I would be) East. so shouldn't I feel at least a bit of it against my face?

Comment: No, GianLuca, forget the Earth is rotating. For such short distances and slow speeds (as you running one way or other), you must consider the Earth is **not** moving. If you run East or West and there is no wind, of course, the only wind is the one you are creating. In the same way,if you throw a ball/stone East or West you need the same KE.   Hope it's clear now.

Comment: @GianLucaSpadafora, if it is not yet clear, just imagine you  on a train speeding a 300 Km/h West, and you running up and down the corridor. You are slowing down in one case, will you feel a **different** wind on your face?